# Create a local Laravel dev environment with Docker

Tags: docker

```
version: '3'


networks:
 - laravel


services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
       - "8088:80"
    volumes:
       - ./src:/var/www/html
       - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
        - php
        - mysql
    networks:
        - laravel
  mysql:
        image: mysql:5.7.22
        container_name: mysql
        restart: unless-stopped
        tty: true
        ports:
          - "4306:3306"
        volumes:
          - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
          MYSQL_DATABASE: homestead
          MYSQL_USER: root
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: 
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 
          SERVICE_TAGS: dev
          SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    networks:
       - laravel

  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: php
    volumes:
       - ./src:/var/www/html
    ports:
       - "9000:9000"
   networks:
      - laravel
```

this is my dock-compose.yml file but while running `docker-compose build && docker-compose up -d`

command yaml: line 37: did not find expected key error is coming

Comment: YML doesn't need  `-`  indents. use space instead. As well **alignments are way too important in docker YML** check [this](https://www.cloudsigma.com/deploying-laravel-nginx-and-mysql-with-docker-compose/) and  [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-laravel-nginx-and-mysql-with-docker-compose)